# How to display data from DataGrid into TextField in VB6.0?

Tags: sql-server, vb6

I am using VB6.0 and SQL server 2008. I use `DataGrid` control in my work. I know how to populate the database records into DataGrid. But how to display the selected row from DataGrid into text boxes?

Comment: i used this code to populate the datagrid.                             sql2 = "select * from employee"
rs.Open sql2, con, 3, 1, adCmdText
Set DataGrid1.DataSource = rs

Answer (score 0):

At least two ways.

One is to use data binding on your TextBox controls and assigning the same DataSource.

Another is based on the DataGrid's SelChange event and SelBookmarks property, as described in the Fine Manual:

> When a record is selected in the DataGrid control, its bookmark is appended to the collection returned by the SelBookmarks property. For example, if you create a clone of the Recordset object created by the DataGrid control, you can process individual data records by repositioning the cloned Recordset with bookmarks taken from the SelBookmarks collection.